# How to retain text in a textfield after poping the page

Tags: flutter, dart

Screen 1 and Screen 2. Screen 2 has a text field. How can I retain the text in screen 2 after poping this page and going back to screen 1, Then navigating back to screen 2?

Demo code:
Screen 1:

```
   class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  void _nextPage() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _nextPage,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen 2:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  final control = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: control,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- Screen 1 navigates me to Screen 2.
- I input value in the textfield in screen 2
- I navigate back to screen 1
- Then I go to screen 2 again.
- Text no longer shows in textfield. (I want previous text to still be there.)

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to pass the text back to screen1 and then when navigating pass the text to screen2 in constructor.

### Screen 1

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  String? _text;
  void _nextPage() async {
    _text = await Navigator.push<String>(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<String>(builder: (context) => const SecondPage(text: _text)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _nextPage,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Screen2

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key, this.text,});
  final String? text;
  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  final control = TextEditingController(widget.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, control.text);
        },
      )),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: control,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Second solution

According to comments:
a second solution that might work is to use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`
For more information of this mixin see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

### Screen2

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key,});
  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final control = TextEditingController();

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: control,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

important is here to call `super.build` in the build method

Comment: that could work in some cases but not in the case I am trying to implement it with.  I have a chat application... So the idea is when the user types in the text field of one chat.. and goes back to the chat list. Reopens the chat, the text should still be there.  What I just thought of now is for a way to store the state. Maybe by using a provider and using the family parameter for a provider.

Comment: i edited my answer, see second solution with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`